# Perform deviating math operations on list in correct order

Tags: python, math

Given a list of values (One of them is a numpy array.):

arr = np.array([3, 2, 6])

values = [2, arr, 8, 3]

and a list of math operators connecting these values:

math_operators = [+, *, -].

Is there a function in Python, which let's me calculate the resulting formula (x = 2 + arr * 8 - 3) in the right order?

the operator.add() etc. functions from the operator package do not solve this problem, since the order (Here: * before +/ -) needs to be ensured with lot'sof biolerplate code. I believe there must be an easier solution to this.

Comment: What are the values in `math_operators`? strings?

Comment: In this example they are strings. If there is a python way to save these math operators in variables, then this could be a part of the solution I guess.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)

Comment: Thank you for finding this! It answers the question. However, in my real example one of the integers could be a numpy array, saved in a variable, which is not detected by the solution. I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: The built-in `eval` does that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array

operator_precedences = [['**'], ['*', '/', '//', '%'], ['+', '-']]

def derivate(values, operators):
    for of_precedence in operator_precedences:
        for operator in of_precedence:
            while operator in operators:
                idx = operators.index(operator)
                left = repr(values[idx])
                right = repr(values[idx+1])
                expression = f'{left} {operators[idx]} {right}'
                result = eval(expression)
                values = values[:idx] + [result] + values[idx+2:]
                operators = operators[:idx] + operators[idx+1:]
    return values[0]

values = [2, np.array([3, 2, 6]), 8, 3, 2]
operators = ['+', '*', '-', '**']
expected_result = 2 + np.array([3, 2, 6]) * 8 - 3 ** 2

derived_result = derivate(values, operators)
assert all(derived_result == expected_result)
```

How it works:

Iterate over the operator groups from highest to lowest precedence, and iterate over the operators in the group. For each occurrence of an operator in the provided `operators` (at index `idx`), perform the respective operation `values[idx] operators[idx] values[idx+1]` and update `values` by removing `values[idx]` and `values[idx+1]` and inserting the result and update `operators` by removing `operators[idx]`.

(Edit) An alternative solution without using the "evil" `eval` method:

```
operator_mapping = {
    '**': lambda x, y: x ** y,
    '*': lambda x, y: x * y,
    '/': lambda x, y: x / y,
    '//': lambda x, y: x // y,
    '%': lambda x, y: x % y,
    '+': lambda x, y: x + y,
    '-': lambda x, y: x - y
}

def derivate(values, operators):
    for of_precedence in operator_precedences:
        for operator in of_precedence:
            function = operator_mapping[operator]
            while operator in operators:
                idx = operators.index(operator)
                result = function(values[idx], values[idx+1])
                values = values[:idx] + [result] + values[idx+2:]
                operators = operators[:idx] + operators[idx+1:]
    return values[0]
```